# Flows are Stable Under Diffeomorphism

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, differential, diffeomorphism

In chapter 2 of [this book](https://books.google.ch/books?hl=en&lr=&id=ArEJCAAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=the%20structure%20of%20diffeomorphism%20groups&ots=dCXZYF5tmT&sig=DhGnQkgGrcpeqo7XM8AKw32CxN4&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=the%20structure%20of%20diffeomorphism%20groups&f=false) (entitled: The Simplicity Of Diffeomorphism Groups) the author says that given any compactly supported smooth vector field $V$ on a simply connected and connected (finite-dimensional) manifold $M$, the corresponding flow map is stable under conjugation by compactly-supported diffeomorphisms.

Namely, let $F^V$ be map sending $x$ to $f(1)$ where $f$ solves the ODE (locally on some chart):
$$
\frac{\partial_t f}{\partial t} = V(f(t)) \, f(0)=x.
$$
Let $\phi:M\to M$ be a compactly supported diffeomorphism of $M$ (ie: outside some compact $\phi$ is the identity map) then
$$
\phi^{-1}\circ f\circ \phi,
$$
is again a solution to an ODE above?  Why is this the case?  $f\circ \phi$ is clear but I don't see why $\phi^{-1}$ again gives a flow....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Precomposition by $\phi$ just changes the initial point of your flow so I'll leave that to you.  For the rest, we need that $\phi^{-1}$ is at-least $C^1$, which we have in your case.  Let's argue locally so, WLOG, we identify an open nhd of $f\circ \phi(x)$ with $\mathbb{R}^d$.

By the chain-rule we have that
$$
(\phi^{-1}\circ f)'(t) = (\phi^{-1})'(f(t))f'(t) = (\phi^{-1})'(f(t))V(f(t)) = \tilde{V}(f(t)).
$$
Where $\tilde{V}(x)=(\phi^{-1})'(x)V(x)$ and the product is continuous since $\phi^{-1}\in C^1$ and $V$ was $C^1$ by your hypothesis.

So
$
\phi^{-1}\circ f\circ \phi
$
is again a flow!

Comment: Thanks, I guess it was pretty clear after all...